# Openlayers add loading indicator using prerender and postrender events

Tags: javascript, dom, openlayers

It's about VectorImage:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_VectorImage-VectorImageLayer.html

I can't get it to work properly. For testing purposes, I add a fullscreen div on top of my map in the prerender event and remove this div in postrender event. In the end, I want to add a spinning loading animation in the middle of my div and block map interaction, if rendering process is going on.

I have two divs, one for the map and one for the loading indicator:

```
<div id="map" class="map">
<div id="test" class="overlay"></div>
```

My css styles:

```
.map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
     }

html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%}
div {width:100px;height:100%;}

.overlay {  
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            z-index:1000;
            background-color:red;
          }
```

Global reference

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");
```

And the events

```
vectorLayer.on('postrender', function(event) {
    myDiv.remove();
    console.log('post');
});

vectorLayer.on('prerender', function(e) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myDiv);
    console.log('pre');
});
```

With that code I see my div at the beginning. When my map is ready, the div is being removed. But with any other interaction my div never beeing added, even if I can clearly see the logs in the console, that the events are fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using styles instead of removing and appending the element, something like this:

```
<div id="test" class="overlay hidden"></div>
```

with CSS:

```
.hidden {  
  display: none;
}
```

Then remove the class on `prerender` and add it on `postrender`.

Otherwise, you could try console logging `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` and `myDiv` to see if the correct element is being appended to the correct parent.

Comment: 1. What do you see when you call `console.log(myDiv);` on `prerender`?

2. Can you show a fiddle with your code? Here's a quick sample I made using a red overlay that is shown when user moves the map: https://jsfiddle.net/w3yxdc9m/

Comment: thanks for your help, here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/komarara/5mbowshu/17/   onPrerender I can see that the hidden class is being removed, which is correct but there is no red div appears.

Comment: Hmm, that might be because `postrender` occurs so fast after `prerender` - the render process is so quick that the overlay doesn't have time to appear. If you add a timeout, such as `setTimeout(() => redDiv.classList.add("hidden"), 500);` you can see that the overlay does appear.

Comment: The div does not appear because the main thread is already blocked by openlayers. This problem is not trivial